# How can I select the first element of a node with XSL?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm coding my first website using XML+XSL. The xml I am transforming have this section:

```
<page>
    <news>
        <highlights>
            <entry>
                <mini>x_thumb.jpg</mini>
                <title>title</title>
                <text>text</text>
                <image>x.jpg</image>
                <link>x.html</link>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <mini>z_thumb.jpg</mini>
                <title>title</title>
                <text>text</text>
                <image>z.jpg</image>
                <link>z.html</link>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <mini>y_thumb.jpg</mini>
                <title>title</title>
                <text>text</text>
                <image>y.jpg</image>
                <link>y.html</link>
            </entry>
        </highlights>
    </news>
</page>
```

In my .xsl file I want to select the first entry because I'm doing a jQuery image rotator and I need the "default" image to show it. So I coded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        [...]

        <xsl:template match="page/news/highlights/entry[1]"> 
            <div class="main_image">
                <img>
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                        <xsl:value-of select="image" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </img> 
                <div class="desc"> 
                    <div class="block"> 
                        <p>
                            <xsl:value-of select="text" />
                        </p> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div>
        </xsl:template>
[...]
```

And I can't get it working. I've tried various ways, like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="page/news/highlights/entry[1]/image" />
```

An no way... How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you want to select all the entries, and hide all but the first with jQuery?

What exactly are youtrying to do differently with the first element?

Comment: I was reproducing: http://designm.ag/tutorials/image-rotator-css-jquery/ but with dejavu answer now I get it working! Thanks! :)

Comment: You are always talking about "it" ("I can't get it working", "How can I do it?") without clearly defining what "it" is. Do not assume people know about or care for the inner workings of the particular jQuery image plugin you are using. Just showing the desired output will be enough for XSLT questions. *PS: Also, please post a syntactically legal code sample next time. This will help people reproduce your problem without the need to guess.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <!-- [...] -->

  <!-- show first entry only -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="page/news/highlights/entry[1]" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- generic template to handle <entry> elements -->
<xsl:template match="entry"> 
  <div class="main_image">
    <!-- Attribute Value Templates save many lines of code --> 
    <img src="{image}" alt="{title}" />
    <div class="desc"> 
      <div class="block"> 
        <p><xsl:value-of select="text" /></p> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry Tomalak for my bad expresion. As you can see English is not my main language. I'm sorry for the confusion I've caused. I've to say that your answer helped me a lot and it's what I'm using. Thank you!

Comment: @Isem: No need to not apologize. You should have fixed your question instead.

Comment: Also you could match first `entry` like `match="entry[1]"` and overwrite text nodes' built-inrule with an empty rule for compacting code.

Comment: @Alejandro: I consider writing a distinct template for a single node a code smell in XLST. I deliberately did not choose do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:value-of select="page/news/highlights/entry[position() = 1]/image" />
```

Comment: @Isem Palaus: If that worked, then you had something else wrong. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev and in section 2.4, "Thus a location path `para[3]` is equivalent to `para[position()=3]`"

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
<xsl:foreach select="page/news/highlights/entry">
    <div>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">main_image</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <img>
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="image" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </img> 
        <div class="desc"> 
            <div class="block"> 
                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                </p> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</xsl>
```